# PI number calculating with c++ program

Tags: c++

```
// PI = 4 - (4/3) + (4/5) - (4/7) ... for 100 first statements
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double PI = 0.0;
    int a = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            PI += double(4 / a);
        }
        else {
            PI -= double(4 / a);
        }
        a += 2;
    }
    cout << "PI Number is : " << PI;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried this code in visual studio 2015 to give me the answer of PI number value but it returns "PI Number is : 3" and I want it to return a float or a double number.

What should I do?

Comment: Try replacing `double(4 / a)` with `4.0 / a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is when it's computing the value:

```
double PI = 0.0;
int a = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        PI += double(4 / a);
    }
    else {
        PI -= double(4 / a);
    }
    a += 2;
}
```

You shouldn't do `double(4 / a)` but rather `(double)4 / a` or `4.0 / a`

```
double PI = 0.0;
int a = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        PI += (double)4 / a;
    }
    else {
        PI -= (double)4 / a;
    }
    a += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In `double(4 / a)`, the `4 / a` part evaluates to an integer and it is already truncated by the time you cast it to `double`. What you want to do is `4.0 / a` instead, and no need for an explicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

`4 / a` is an integer division and your conversion `double(…)` happens **after** that division, so the result will never have something after the decimal point. e.g. `4/5` results in `0`.

You need to change `4` from an integer to a double `4.`